# php email script doesn't work

Tags: email, php

I have this script:

```
<?php
    $to1 = $_GET["number"];
    $to2 = $_GET["at"];
    $subject = $_GET["sub"];
    $message = $_GET["message"];
    $from = "admin@chipperyman573.com";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $fin = $to1+"@"+$to2;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

I go to this url:

```
http://chipperyman573.com/send.php?to1=whatsittoya573&to2=gmail.com&subject=Test&message=Test2
```

however I get no email in my gmail inbox. admin@chipperyman573.com does exist.

Comment: What have you done to troubleshoot this, what is the return value of `mail()`?

Comment: youre gonna have to post more than that....like perhaps the mail class?

Comment: @jeroen How do I get a return value? I am new to PHP.

Comment: @KyleK That's all I have. Like I said I'm new to PHP.

Comment: you know it is almost a guarantee to get spam if you post your email in a post here?

Comment: Assign the value `$result = mail(...);` and do a `var_dump($result);` to check and process the result. But you really should display errors as that would have notified you of the undefined variables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: As Kolink mentioned, you can't add two strings together with `+`, use `.` (period) instead. Also use `var_dump($_GET)` to check whether all the fields are set.

Comment: @TheKawlr You should not change the original code in your question according to the answers you receive as that leads to answers that make no sense although they might be correct.

Comment: use PhpMailer or Swift mailer those are better ... also make sure you are using SPF and DKIM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the link, you say `subject=Test`, but you use it like `$subject = $_GET["sub"];`?

Try this: `$subject = $_GET["subject"];`

Solved over chat, transcript:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're passing an invalid variable `$to` to `mail`

```
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

should be...

```
mail($fin,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You define `$fin` but never use it. You use `$to` but never declare it.

This might have something to do with it not working ;)

Comment: `.` is the concatenation operator, not `+`.

Comment: may be op come from java or javascript where + is concatenation operator ...but it should  not excuse  :)

Comment: What does the function return? Wrap `var_dump(...)` around it and see what it gives you. Another thing to try is properly ending the header by adding `"\r\n"` to the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this...

```
<?php
$to1 = $_GET["number"];
$to2 = $_GET["at"];
$subject = $_GET["sub"];
$message = $_GET["message"];
$from = "admin@chipperyman573.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
$fin = $to1."@".$to2;
mail($fin,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```